# Is it possible to use the :not() selector to target specific text nodes?

Tags: html, dom, web-scraping, css-selectors

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="status-date">
  <strong>Date Available:</strong> 
  10/05/2016
</div>
```

I'd expect the `:not()` selector to be capable of targeting the date string "10/05/2016" as follows:

```
.status-date *:not(strong) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Two questions**:
1. Is the `:not()` selector capable of this?
2. If not, is *any* CSS selector capable of this?

**Context**: this is actually not about *styling* the text nodes. I am doing some web scraping and I'd like to ignore the `<strong>` tag in this case. If it were about styling, I could target the `div` directly and overwrite the styles on the `<strong>` to "cancel it out".

**Further context**: I can see that my naïve attempt doesn't work as expected. For example, as shown in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWezQK
 But it's possible I'm misunderstanding something deep about the selector or the DOM structure I've described.

Comment: The answer to your first question is: did you try it?

Comment: Of course, and it does not seem to work. But I thought it possible I was misunderstanding the spec. The specification itself offers only three lines on the `:not()` selector.

Comment: Well seems as if you are. Doing `.status-date *` only selects the HTML elements, not text nodes.

Comment: for your example, here is the way to do it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbyEYX . CSS do not access text nodes anyway.  Your selector :not() ,if you drop the text node idea :) ,  works fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WowZvZ

Comment: *"I am doing some web scraping and I'd like to ignore the <strong> tag in this case."* - you probably should elaborate further on what you're actually trying to achieve. Anyway, this smells like a job for XPath instead of CSS selectors.

Comment: @the8472 I want the well-structured date without the "Date available:" tag. I can strip it using JavaScript before I store the date itself, but it would be convenient if a simple selector could grab it out-of-the-box.

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you, but I specifically said that I was not interested in that solution. I am not actually trying to style anything, only using a scrape tool that uses CSS selectors, so overwriting the `<strong>` styles is not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple selectors represent elements. This is true for all simple selectors, including `*` and `:not()`. Text is contained by an element, but is not an element in its own right. You won't be able to "match" just the text with any CSS selector, because as far as selectors are concerned, what the DOM calls text nodes don't even exist in the document tree.

> The specification itself offers only three lines on the `:not()` selector.

The first line in the specification supports this:

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

Notice that it says "It represents an element".

If you're doing web scraping, consider XPath:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' status-date ')]/strong/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a comprehensive and direct answer to my explicit question, with a concrete suggestion for solving my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, CSS cannot affect text-nodes that are not wrapped in a container. Hence, the :not-selector is not capable of doing what you're trying to do. If you're gonna scrape information like this, you will have to parse it server-side - or just set `div strong { display: none; }` for *viewing* the content - but that will probably not affect the scraping bit...